# TIme complexity of unoptimal power set algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```py
def subsetsWithDup(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    nums.sort()
    res = [[]]
    self.dfs(nums, res, [], 0)
    return res

def dfs(self, nums, res, path, index):
    if path not in res:
        res.append(path)
    
    for pos in range(index, len(nums)):
        self.dfs(nums, res, path + [nums[pos]], pos+1)
```

Above is an unoptimal algorithm that generates a power set given an array of numbers that can contain duplicates.

I think the time complexity of this algorithm is : n * n! * 2^n,

My logic is as follows:

- we loop the array once per value (n)
- For each loop the number of calls is (n-1)! which is n! complexity
- Then there is a check if value in array in each call which has at most 2^n checks since that's when power set is complete but dupes are being checked
- Combining them gives n*n!*2^n

Is this correct ?

Thank you